# Match string between () and not inside quotes

Tags: regex

My current attempt `(?<=[,(][^"]).*(?=[,)][^"])`

```
("WideCharToMultiByte", "uint", 0, "uint", 0x400, "uint", Address, "int", Length, "str", String, "int", char_count, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vd3w7C/3/

How do I match everything inside the `( )` less things inside quotes?

Match only: `0` `address` `length` `string` `char_count` `0` `0`

Comment: Something like `(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\()"[^"]*"(?:,\s*"[^"]*")*\K,\s*\K[^\s,)]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vd3w7C/5))?

Comment: Yes, wow, don't think it was going to be so complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a PCRE/Onigmo compatible regex engine, you can use

```php
(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\()(?:,?\s*"[^"]*")*,\s*\K[^\s,)]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ST2IjV/2).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\()` - either the end of the previous successful match and then a `,` and zero or more whitespaces, or a `(` char
- `(?:,?\s*"[^"]*")*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `,?` - an optional comma
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far in the overall match memory buffer
- `[^\s,)]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace, `,` and `)`.